# WP_Query post_parent parameter always returns children of current page

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, plugin-polylang

Well the title gives it all away...

Here's the code:

```
$args = array(
"post_type" => "page",
"post_parent" => $cat, // runs through a loop of 5, 128, 130
"posts_per_page" => -1
);

print_r($args);

$postsLang = new WP_Query($args);

while ($postsLang->have_posts()) {
    $postsLang->the_post();
    $postID = get_the_ID();
    array_push($result, $postID);
}
wp_reset_query();

print_r($result);
```

Here the print_r outputs:

```
Array ( [post_type] => page [post_parent] => 5 [posts_per_page] => -1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 23 ) 

Array ( [post_type] => page [post_parent] => 128 [posts_per_page] => -1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 23 ) 

Array ( [post_type] => page [post_parent] => 130 [posts_per_page] => -1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 23 )
```

So the $args go into the query correctly, but the outcome is always the same: the IDs of the children of the current page (ID = 5).

I can even set post_parent static to say 128 and still get the children of the current page.

If I remove the post_parent parameter I get all pages (as I should).

I'm having the same issue with get_posts, which makes me think that the syntax is right but that I might be misunderstanding the behaviour of the post_parent parameter?!

Any thoughts much appreciated!!

Comment: I think you should reset `wp_reset_postdata();` instead of `wp_reset_query();`.

Comment: Hm, just checked, no changes. Even with resetting both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`post_parent`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) returns **only** the child pages of the page whose ID is given as the value.

> **post_parent** (int) - use page id to return only child pages. Set to 0 to return only top-level entries

To get just a specific page, rather use `page_id` or `pagename` or `post__in` (in conjunction with `post_type=page`.

I would suggest that you rather make use of [`get_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) which is specifically there to query pages.

Just a note here, `wp_reset_query()` is used in conjunction with `query_posts`. You should use `wp_reset_postdata()` with `WP_Query`

--

Here the solution from the comments below:

Polylang creates a new custom parameter "lang". This parameter appears to default to "", which is supposed to return posts with [any](http://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/general/) value. Instead it returns posts with the current page's language value only (hence only children of current page ID = 5). As a fix I now manually loop through the available values for "lang" to get pages with all values for "lang". I'll check with the plugin author if this is a bug or caused by my environment.

Comment: Thanks for digging in! I _do_ want to get the child pages. First of page 5, then of 128, then of 130. My parameters going into the query correctly, but the query seems to reset the post_parent parameter to the current page's ID.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Where exactly, on which template, are you using this. Is this on a page.php template. Are **all** custom queries reset. Try to add `wp_reset_query()` **before** your query

Comment: This is on a plain-ish template and page but I just realized that the issue goes away when I deactivate the polylang plugin! `wp_reset_query()` before the query does not help. Is there a way to safeguard the WP_Query from being messed with _after_ the parameters have been set? I don't understand how at this point polylang (or anything else for that matter) can interfere with the query?!

Comment: Do you have any instance of `pre_get_posts` somewhere. Also, have cleared **all** caches and have you tried switching to a bundled theme. Post the complete page template. You can just remove any markup

Comment: What seems to be the cause

Comment: No `pre_get_posts` instances. But I think I just found the solution: Polylang creates a new custom parameter "lang". This parameter appears to default to "", which is supposed to return posts with [any](http://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/general/) value. Instead it returns posts with the current page's language value only (hence only children of current page ID = 5). As a fix I now manually loop through the available values for "lang" to get pages with all values for "lang". I'll check with the plugin author if this is a bug or caused by my environment.

Comment: Great. I hope this pans out for you. Enjoy :-)